# Can stored SQL proedures be debugged in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, stored-procedures, mariadb

I would like to single step a stored procedure, is there a plugin for eclipse that allows this?

I'm using MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has no built-in support for debugging stored procedures in *any* database. The nature of stored procs are highly proprietary and vendor-specific, so the only hope for such a thing would be a custom plug-in provided by a RDBMS vendor. I know of no such plug-ins for any of the major databases, certainly never seen any Eclipse plug-ins for MariaDB.